# Does Creating Variable when it is needed will help in performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Will creating Variable whenever needed in Stored Procedure or Function or Trigger helps in performance optimization?
Which one is better of below or both have same performance?

> **Option 1:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateAmount] ON [RequestDB].[dbo].[Invoice]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 IF UPDATE(Service_Amount)
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @NewService_Amount float,@OldService_Amount float //Var Created When needed
  SELECT @NewService_Amount = I.Service_Amount FROM INSERTED I
  SELECT @OldService_Amount = D.Service_Amount FROM DELETED D   
  IF (@NewService_Amount <> @OldService_Amount)
  BEGIN
   SELECT @InvId = I.Id FROM INSERTED I 
   DECLARE @DiffService_Amount float //Var Created When needed
   SET @DiffService_Amount = @NewService_Amount - @OldService_Amount
   UPDATE [RequestDB].[dbo].[Request] SET Actual_Amount = @DiffService_Amount WHERE Invoice_Id = @InvId
  END
 END
END
```

> **Option 2:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateAmount] ON [RequestDB].[dbo].[Invoice]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @NewService_Amount float,@OldService_Amount float.@DiffService_Amount float //All Var Created at once on top of code
 IF UPDATE(Service_Amount)
 BEGIN
  SELECT @NewService_Amount = I.Service_Amount FROM INSERTED I /*For New UPDATE Value: INSERTED. For Old BEFORE UPDATE Valie: DELETED*/
  SELECT @OldService_Amount = D.Service_Amount FROM DELETED D   
  IF (@NewService_Amount <> @OldService_Amount)
  BEGIN
   SELECT @InvId = I.Id FROM INSERTED I 
   SET @DiffService_Amount = @NewService_Amount - @OldService_Amount
   UPDATE [RequestDB].[dbo].[Request] SET Actual_Amount = @DiffService_Amount WHERE Invoice_Id = @InvId
  END
 END
END
```

Comment: You might want to read up on this first : http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/05/triggers-set-based-not-row-based/

Comment: Agreed with granadaCoder - since both are incorrect in assuming that `inserted` and `deleted` contain a single row, it's not an area I'd be focussing on. Once you switch to performing a set based `UPDATE`, there probably won't be any local variables at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx) don't get too specific about variables other than to say that once it's declared it's available through that batch process:

> The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

My *assumption* would be declaring it later is better (given how they word the docs)--if you don't use it, avoid declaring it. **However**, the real answer would be to test it and profile it. Whichever works better in *practice* would be the real solution, IMHO.

I also hope this isn't a premature optimization. If you're down to declaration order to make your scripts run faster, you're probably looking in the wrong spot.

Comment: Meaning the overhead of a variable declaration isn't the spot to interrogate for performance gain; it's like picking out aerodynamic shoe laces on your favorite running shoes to cut time off your sprint.

Comment: If you were declaring table variables this may be a big issues (I still think it's not the problem, but given the larger memory footprint it could be argued), but determining where a `float` should be declared isn't even worth researching. If it's going slow then profile the query and see how it's executing (does bringing in tables slow it down, dot he PKs make sense, etc.)